# Why does inserting a vertex with the same property not throw an error in DSE Graph?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am using Dse graph **version 5.x.**

I have created a schema using Dse studio which uses gremlin query.

What I am trying to do is:

I want to index my graph based on vertex property called 'name'

Here is what I get when I do **`schema.describe()`**
[image: Schema Image]

Here is what I get when I do **`g.V()`**
[image: graph table]

As you can clearly see, I have index my vertex label `type` with property `name`.

**But when I insert multiple vertex (of label `type`) with same `name` it accept it without error.**

**Ideally because of indexing it should show error on inserting vertex with same property `name'.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

indexing in DSE Graph is a performance optimization operation not a Referential Integrity operation.  Currently there is no mechanism that will "reject" creating a new index if one exists with the same property.  We have this feature request on our roadmap.  In the interim, it is possible to achieve "upsert" style semantics with DSE Graph by leveraging Custom IDs as described here - http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/createCustVertexId.html?hl=custom%2Cid

Comment: when we can expect this feature

Comment: There is no timeline tied to this feature at this date.  Note, you can achieve this behavior using the Graph Loader tool when executing bulk loading job.s